# Confused about MongoDB and Pooling, also Bson syntax and Document formats

Tags: java, database, mongodb, bson

I've only just started using MongoDB (2 hours in) and I'm super confused about a few things.

Firstly, I read that MongoDB connection pooling isn't needed as it already does that for you. Is this true?

Secondly, I am creating profiles in a collection, the some of the profiles may have information like expiry dates, and passwords, some do not. Is it possible to just set their document to contain these and still be a member of the same collection?

Thirdly, I'm using the UUID for each document, would this be the way to retrieve a specific document:

```
public static Document getPlayer(String uuid) {
    return players.find(Document.parse("{uuid : " + uuid + "}")).first();
}
```

Is the syntax correct? I currently don't have the ability to run the code as I do not have a MongoDB server.

Thank you for your help.. I am currently reading through the docs and learning more and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, I read that MongoDB connection pooling isn't needed as it
>   already does that for you. Is this true?

Whenever you create a [mongoClient](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoClient.html) is has a connection pool associated with it.
You're essentially not required to handle these connections yourself but use a single client object throughout your application. You may want to take a look at [connection](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/) document here.

> Secondly, I am creating profiles in a collection, the some of the
>   profiles may have information like expiry dates, and passwords, some
>   do not. Is it possible to just set their document to contain these and
>   still be a member of the same collection?

This is absolutely possible in MongoDB. It allows you to store polymorphic data in a single collection.

> Thirdly, I'm using the UUID for each document, would this be the way
>   to retrieve a specific document.

Take a look at the read operations done in [this doc](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/).

Sample:

```
collection.find(
    new Document("stars", new Document("$gte", 2)
          .append("$lt", 5))
          .append("categories", "Bakery")).forEach(printBlock);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for clearing all of that up for me. One more thing; I’m using MongoDB on a minecraft network so each server will have a MongoClient object. Is this safe? Are there any precautions? Thank you again sir.

Comment: That should be fine

Comment: You've really helped me out @Astro, makes perfect sense now. Thank you very much. *Answer accepted*